# How to disable Android MediaPlayer debug messages

Tags: android, media-player, logcat, message

When using MediaPlayer I get the following lines of debug messages in LogCat constantly repeating:

```
02-13 14:30:52.090: V/MediaPlayer(21345): getVideoWidth
02-13 14:30:52.090: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(21345): getVideoWidth: 480
02-13 14:30:52.090: V/MediaPlayer(21345): getVideoHeight
02-13 14:30:52.090: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(21345): getVideoHeight: 360
02-13 14:30:52.100: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(21345): isPlaying: 0
```

My buffer soon fills up and I miss my other important messages. Is there anyway to disable this? Doing an exclusive filter in LogCat doesn't work because the buffer is still filled up in the background.

Comment: show me your code please

Comment: do you know messages like this `02-13 17:32:02.174: W/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 92 msecs, 350 delayed writes, thread 0xb3f0` ?

Comment: I can't share the code sorry but I haven't seen any messages like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove it by adding `^(?!MediaPlayer)` to logcat filter `Log Tag (regex)` field: https://www.evernote.com/l/ABjh04WocVlGBp_wUBuQyefZIc_9aa8WP8QB/image.png

Answer (score 1):

I've also searched a solution to this problem and it seems that it is not possible at all...
As you can see, no method is available.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible because most of than are logged by C++ implementation. As you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java?av=f), MediaPlayer is a kind of C++ wrapper to call native methods through Java.

E.g. [seekTo(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.seekTo%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider increasing your log level to Debug. Most of the noisy logging MediaPlayer spits out is logged as verbose.